# PostgreSQL - table with foreign key column needs to be updated first

Tags: database, postgresql

I have encountered a problem in my project using PostgreSQL.

Say there are two tables `A` and `B`, both `A` and `B` have a (unique) field named `ID`. The `ID` column of table `A` is declared as a primary key, while the `ID` column of table `B` is declared as a foreign key pointing back to table `A`.

My problem is that every time we have new data inputted into database, the values in table `B` tend to be updated prior to the ones in table `A` (this problem can not be avoided as the project is designed this way). So I have to modify the relationship between `A` and `B`.

My goal is to achieve a situation where I can insert data into `A` and `B` separately while having the `ON DELETE CASCADE` clause enabled. What's more, INSERT and DELETE queries may happen at the same time.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How about create table `C` and have a referential integrity A.ID on C.ID and B.X on C.ID.  Insert into C first then B and A later. Delete C with cascade option.

Comment: If you are doing all the inserts and updates in a single transaction you can define the constraints as deferred and they will only be checked at commit time (when you end the transaction)

Comment: Wow, thanks to both of your advice! Never used SET CONSTRAINT and DEFERRED before, and it's really a good method! Thanks, horse! Unfortunately, in my project, inserting to A and B can't be involved into one transaction, so I may choose the tricky one with a new table C added!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a badly designed project, if you can't use deferred constraints.  Your basic problem is that you can't guarantee internal consistency of the data because transactions may occur which do not  move the data from one consistent state to another.

Here is what I would do to be honest:

1. Catalog affected keys.
2. Drop affected key constraints.
3. Write a periodic job that looks for orphaned rows.  Use LEFT JOIN because antijoins do not perform as well in PostgreSQL.

The problem with a third table is it doesn't solve your basic problem, which is that writes are not atomically consistent.  And once you sacrifice that a lot of your transactional controls go out the window.

Long term, the project needs to be rewritten.